# Inserir uma animação do Adobe edge no tema Zerif do Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, animação

Isso é muito específico, não sei se podem me ajudar. Esse tema tem várias sessões, que nada mais são que páginas PHP que são importadas. Criei uma nova página chamada "animacao" e importei no tema com o código:

```
get_template_part( 'sections/animacao' );
```

Até aí funciona normal. Mas quero colocar uma animação que fiz no Edge Animate CC. O edge gera um HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"     src="edge_includes/edge.6.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-709063 { visibility:hidden; }
    </style>
<script>
   AdobeEdge.loadComposition('teste', 'EDGE-709063', {
    scaleToFit: "none",
    centerStage: "none",
    minW: "0px",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "550px",
    height: "400px"
}, {dom: [ ]}, {dom: [ ]});
</script>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div id="Stage" class="EDGE-709063">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Coloquei os arquivos Javascript que acompanham o HTML da animacao na pasta "Sections" e no "root", mas nada é exibido quando o site roda, fica apenas um espaço em branco onde era para rodar a animação. Se rodo a animação em uma página separada funciona normal.

Comment: Os arquivos Javascript estão sendo carregados na página? se sim, quantas vezes? Se tentar carregar mais de uma vez ele pode entrar em conflito

Comment: O javascript é carregado apenas na página da animação mesmo. Tentei deixar a importação dos scripts no header do tema e deixar só a div mesmo ficar no sections/animacao, mas também não aparece nada.

Comment: Tenta tirar quaisquer outro arquivo JS da pagina pra ver se ele carrega. Se carregar, vai voltando 1 a 1 pra ver qual da conflito. Não é a melhor solução, mas pode ser que funcione. Uma vez aconteceu algo assim comigo, tiver que caçar 1 a 1 ate achar onde tava travando meu js ¬¬

Comment: Exclui o Header (onde acontecem as importações de JS) e não funciona também. Fui no JS da animação e pensei ser por causa do diretório das imagens da animação, em vez de  "var im='/images/'", coloquei o link direto para a pasta, mas também não adiantou. Já não sei mais o que pode ser.

Comment: No inspecionar do navegador não mostra nenhum erro de execução de script?

Comment: Sou principiante, esqueço a possibilidade de olhar esses erros de JS no console. http://site/maps_edgeActions.js 404 (Not Found). É questão de diretório mesmo, coloquei lá no root do www em vez do tema e deu certo! Obrigado pela luz!

Comment: De nada, mas essa de esquecer de olhar o console é normal rs.  Que bom que pude ajudar. ^^